# Bamboo Mesos Marathon

Tags: docker, apache-zookeeper, mesos, marathon

I'm trying to setup Bamboo (https://github.com/QubitProducts/bamboo) for my Mesos and Marathon cluster. Currently, my marathon instance is running with the following parameters:

```
MARATHON_EVENT_SUBSCRIBER=http_callback
MARATHON_HTTP_ENDPOINTS=http://my-marathon-server/callback
```

Running `marathon` informs me of the following: `run_jar --zk zk://my-marathon-server:2181/marathon --master zk://my-marathon-server:2181/mesos`

Everything seems to be functioning fine with Mesos + Marathon. However, when I go to run Bamboo on one of my Mesos Slaves, I receive the following error:

```
2015-12-02 03:15:32,525 INFO spawned: 'bamboo' with pid 20
2015-12-02 03:15:32,546 DEBG 'bamboo' stdout output:
2015/12/02 03:15:32 Using environment override MARATHON_ENDPOINT=http://my-marathon-server:8080
2015/12/02 03:15:32 Using environment override BAMBOO_ENDPOINT=http://my-bamboo-server(mesos-slave):8000
2015/12/02 03:15:32 Using environment override BAMBOO_ZK_HOST=my-marathon-server:2181
2015/12/02 03:15:32 Using environment override BAMBOO_ZK_PATH=/bamboo
2015/12/02 03:15:32 Environment variable not set: STATSD_ENABLED
2015/12/02 03:15:32 Starting update loop

2015-12-02 03:15:32,555 DEBG 'bamboo' stdout output:
2015/12/02 03:15:32 bamboo_startup => 2015-12-02T03:15:32Z
2015/12/02 03:15:32 Queuing an haproxy update.

2015-12-02 03:15:32,571 DEBG 'bamboo' stdout output:
[martini] listening on ":8000" (development)
[martini] listen tcp: unknown port tcp/8000"

2015-12-02 03:15:32,577 DEBG fd 7 closed, stopped monitoring <POutputDispatcher at 140685022053728 for <Subprocess at 140685022289000 with name bamboo in state STARTING> (stdout)>
2015-12-02 03:15:32,577 INFO exited: bamboo (exit status 1; not expected)
2015-12-02 03:15:37,685 DEBG received SIGCLD indicating a child quit
2015-12-02 03:15:38,686 INFO gave up: bamboo entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
```

I'm using the `bamboo` docker container to spin up bamboo.

Has anyone else encountered this issue before? Any ideas on what I can do to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Verify that Marathon is making the callback to the right place.  Your Bamboo instance needs to be subscribed to the http_callback in order for everything to work properly.

https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/rest-api.html#event-subscriptions

This is what my subscriptions look like.  I formatted this for readability, so yours might look slightly messier.

```
# curl --silent http://my-mesos-master:8080/v2/eventSubscriptions
{
  "callbackUrls": [
    "http://my-bamboo-server:8000/api/marathon/event_callback"
  ]
}
```

Are you using the `-e BAMBOO_DOCKER_AUTO_HOST=true` switch when you launch your Bamboo Docker container?  I believe that populates the correct host information in the bamboo config.  If that doesn't look right, check your config (defaults to `config/production.example.json`) to make sure the values line up with your environment.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error,
-e BIND="0.0.0.0:8000" 
I changed this config to -e BIND=0.0.0.0:8000, it worked.